# ODB_CONNECT() not working on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, odbc

I am trying to make ODBC connection from windows server 2008 R2, but it shows me this error:

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied., SQL
>   state 08001 in SQLConnect in
>   C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\Divi\cargo_consignment_tracking.php
>   on line 30

**My php version is 7.0.9**

My connection string to connect with the server

```
$server = 'SERVER_IP_ADDRESS';
user = 'USERNAME';
            $pass = 'PASSWORD';
            $port = '1433';
            $database = 'cargo_web';

            //connection string
            $connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$server;$port;DATABASE=$database";
            $conn = odbc_connect($connection_string,$user,$pass);
```

Its working on my localhost server, but not on windows server 2008 R2.

My phpinfo() contains ODBC part and I have enabled odbc connection in php.ini with these lines

```
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_odbc.dll
```

Why am I facing this issue on the server ??

Comment: Please check SQL server is running on Windows Server 2008 also check your server firewall for SQL and check do you have necessary permission to connect to server.

Comment: server is running, because its giving me response on localhost

Comment: just do telnet from your pc to windows server 2008 on sql port,

    telnet <windows_server_2008_IP> 1433

telnet is not installed by default. You can install it from Add/Remove programs in windows components.

Comment: @Shoaib "Could not open connection to the host" . I use telnet and it shows me this error

Comment: Your server is not allowing you to connect there are 2 possible issues,
1. your sql user don't  have permission to connect from your pc to windows server 2008.
2. Windows Server 2008 firewall is not allowing you to connect. please check firewall rules for sql server and check it's in allowed rules.

Comment: this might help you [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2340/resolving-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-errors/)